# Specify a different output css file name with gulp postcss-uncss

Tags: gulp, postcss, uncss, gulp-uncss

Is it possible to specify a different css file name as the output using the gulp plugin `postcss-uncss`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `gulp-rename` plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename